# Searching for factory image of NTT DOCOMO GALAXY Nexus?

Tags: rom-flashing

i am in search of factory image for my new NTT DOCOMO GALAXY Nexus from japan ... i have checked on https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images but could not found for Android 4.0.4 (IMM76K) GSM/HSPA+

actually i wanted to root my device using nexus root toolkit application and that application has detected my device as GSM/HSPA+ , But on the https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images link there is Factory Images "mysid" for Galaxy Nexus "toro" (VZW CDMA/LTE) Android 4.0.4 (IMM76K)

I am not sure CDMA/LTE image can be used, if anything will go wrong while rooting so i can use image to flash device.

please help/suggest me!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Comment: This is a slightly different question though.  Google doesn't really do a great job explaining the differences between the numerous GNex variants.

Answer (score 4):

Hardware-wise, the NTT DoCoMo (SC-04D) and the version sold on Google Play Store (GT-i9250) are identical.  You should be able to use one of the "maguro" takju factory images (ICS or JB.)  Definitely do NOT use the CDMA/LTE image.